# If the Sentry's powers are limitless, can he truly be killed?

Tags: marvel

Many references I've read about The Sentry say his powers are **limitless** and no one actually know what he can't do. So my question is he can truly be killed?

In Seige, Thor kills him with a massive bolt of electricity then used the sun to destroy what was left. However from some sources there was part of the void within Emma Frost that moved on to Cyclops. Is the void part of the Sentry's powers or a complete new entity tied to Robert?

Another 'death' of the Sentry was in 'What If' where Thor snaps his neck. However he has seen to easily defeat Hulk and as it has shown he did defeat Thor.

But can he be killed? Any other information regarding the Sentry's powers and/or apparent death would be great.

Comment: Nobody except Uncle Ben can truely be killed in comics... ;)

Comment: He has seen to easily defeat Hulk ? IIRC at the end of World War Hulk, Hulks wins ? Because Sentry gets back to his human form and falls inconscious whereas Bruce Banner is conscious and soon after gets back into his Hulk form ?

Comment: NikolaiDante - exactly! Sentry was brought back to life during Remender's (poor) Uncanny Avengers arc. Last we saw he tore off his face and I believe was eaten by a giant monster. I do not think he is presumed to be dead but he is totally and utterly insane and overpowered so there's not a great deal they can do with him. If his powers were limitless Thor would not have been able to kill him and Worldbreaker Hulk would not have been able to wear him down to such an extent he reverted back.

Comment: @NikolaiDante - Guess again :-) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncle_Ben#Derailed_Alt-Ben_Parker

Comment: He can't be killed because when the hulk almost killed him with his weakness he was able to over power the hulk with one blow

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> The Sentry has demonstrated the ability to recreate himself after bodily destruction, up to and including total molecular destruction within seconds (he once tried to commit suicide by flying into the heart of the sun). Dialogue between Reynolds and the Void suggests that this particular capability is automatic, involuntary, and beyond the control of either Roberts or the Void.

(*Dark Avengers #15*) Taken from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentry_%28Robert_Reynolds%29).

So it seems unlikely that lightning from Thor will be a final death for him in *Siege #4*.

The incident with Emma Frost was in the Dark Avengers / X-Men crossover [Utopia X](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utopia_%28comics%29), specifically in the *Exodus* one shot and Cyclops took the slither of the void into himself in *Uncanny X-Men #519*

[The Void](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentry_%28Robert_Reynolds%29#Void) itself seems unclear on it's origins with many possibilities listed.

Answer (score 0):

The Sentry is a being of "biblical" decent. References in his history are made to him being connected to various religious events. It is unlikely that the heroes present at the conclusion of siege, even with the norn-stones could kill him. He will definitely be back...

Comment: Are you confusing DC's Spectre with Marvel's Sentry?  There is nothing biblical that I can find in any of the stories about a supernatural or divine origin.

Answer (score 0):

Sentry can't really be killed, almost every time he has supposedly died he willed and begged for death he's never been utterly defeated and disposed of and in seige after Thor ends him and throws him in the sun CLOC lets Mr Fantastic read the fourth page of the sentrys journal and claims it will rebuild the watchtower in await of his return so this says it all the sentry knows nothing of death and his powers are limitless but Robert and the void keep the sentry from reaching full potential along with his mental instability... But from current evidence the sentry is immortal and his powers know no limit so if he was to ever become of one mind and not three and took the time to harness his power no other hero would hold a candle to him not even the hulk or Thor